# No iPhoneOS target in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I am a member of the iPhone developer program. I've created my development certificate and provisioning profile. I've installed both.

However, when I create an empty new xcode project the Target Destination only lists 'Simulator - 3.1.2 | Debug'. For 'Active Architecture', only i386 is listed. However, in the project settings, Architecture is 'arm6' and the Base SDK is 'iPhone Device 3.1.2'. The Code Signing Identity is also set.

My question is, how can I compile for my device? Everything appears to be set up correctly, but there doesn't appear to be anyway to compile for the device.

Comment: does it only happen when you create a completely empty project?  what if you use one of the predefined project types (tab bar, navigation, etc.)

Comment: I've checked some other (older) projects. I appears I can build for 'Device - 2.2.1' but when I open up something that should compile for the 3.0 it says 'Missing | Debug | i386'.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and it appears that /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk was symlinked to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk. I guess upgrading didn't overwrite the symlink.